# Submit form upon selection of browser autocompletion (not custom autocompletion)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, autocomplete

The body of my HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
<form action='http://www.example.com' method='GET'>
    <input type='text' id="text_input"/>
</form>
</body>
```

After entering a couple values into the field and returning to the site, a user is given autocompletion suggestion from the browser.  When you select one, **how can I have the form automatically submit?**

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3736440/2223706), they show something similar in jQuery:

```
$("#text_input").autocomplete({
    source: ['apple', 'banana'],
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        $("#text_input").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#text_input").closest('form').submit(); }
});
```

However, this uses custom autocompletion suggestions, and not the browsers saved results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser auto-completion isn't generally detectable using JS, from the scripts perspective, it will just appear that the user entered some data.

I think the best thing to do would be re-consider your approach to the problem, however if you defiantly want to do it this way:

The closest thing I can think of to what you're after would be to listen for key presses and changes, and a change that occurs with no key presses can be considered an auto-completion.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var keyPressed = false;
  $("#test").on("keydown", function(){
    keyPressed = true;
  });
  $("#test").on("change", function(){
    if(!keyPressed){
      alert("Submit");
    }
  });
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/o60nf4s6/

Issues:

- Also triggered by pasting using the right click context menu
- `change` event is only fired after the input field loses focus
- Any keypress in the input will stop it from submitting, even if auto complete us used. This will only work if the whole input is filled from the browser options.